# ngx chips race condition on blur

Tags: angular, typescript, ngx-chips

```
    <tag-input
      id="enter-tags"
      name="enter-tags"
      [modelAsStrings]="true"
      [addOnBlur]="true"
      [(ngModel)]="tagModel"
      [addOnPaste]="true" [editable]="true">
    </tag-input>
    <button type="submit"
          (click)="PutTagDataToServer()"
          [disabled]="!validateForm()">
         Submit Tags
    </button>
```

I have a race condition between when an tag gets added to my model onblur, and a put to my server, triggered by clicking a submit Bitton.

If I have a tag sitting in the input field, as in it hasn't been added yet to `tagModel`, then I tell my form to submit, I get inconsistent results because the tag gets added to my model asynchronously. Sometimes the put wins the race, some times the tag wins.

I have validation to ensure I have tags, but that still doesn't ensure a tag sitting in the input field, thus not yet appended to `tagModel` , will get added before my put occurs.

What is a good way to resolve this?